# AJAX in Rails 3.2.8 app is not reloading the target div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my layout file I have two pull down menus. When a selection is made in one (category), the contents of the second (item) needs to be updated.

in layout file:

```
<div id="pull_down_items" class="pull-right">
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/pull_down_items' %>
</div>
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/pull_down_category' %>
```

layouts/_pull_down_items.html.erb:

```
<%= select_tag "current_item", options_from_collection_for_select(current_category.items, "id", "item_name", session[:current_item]), :id=>"change_current_item", :remote => true %>
```

layouts/_pull_down_category.html.erb:

```
<%= select_tag "current_category", options_from_collection_for_select(categories, "id", "category_name", session[:current_category]), :id=>"change_current_category", :remote => true %>
```

jQuery in application.js:

```
$("#change_current_category").change(function() {
  var category_id = $(this).val();
  var url = "/system/" + category_id + "/change_category";
  $.post(url, category_id, function(html) {
  });
});
```

In my system_controller:

```
  def change_category
    unless params["id"].blank?
      session[:current_category] = params["id"].to_i
      current_category.reload # this is a method in application_controller.rb
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

in change_team.js.erb:

```
$("#pull_down_items").html("<%= render :partial => 'layouts/pull_down_items' %>")
```

Result: session[:current_category] IS changed to the correct category. The items pull down menu div is NOT reloaded.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `jQuery.post` doesn't guarantee to execute the content it downloads. Try setting `dataType` argument to 'script', as seen on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

> "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.